# Excel SUMIFS formula on using operator inside criteria

Tags: excel-formula, sumifs

`SUMIFS(C1:C5,A1:A5-B1:B5,">5")`

Is the above formula workable in excel?

*Column A* and *Column B* contain dates
*Column C* contains quantity.

What I need is When Column A minus Column B greater than 5 then sum all the quantity.

I understand this is able to do with creating a new column to get the difference in date first then use the computed value inside `SUMIFS` formula.

However, I really try to avoid adding an extra column.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF((A1:A5-B1:B5)>5,C1:C5))
```

**this is an array formula, so press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to calculate the formula.**

Hope this works for you.